# Cache to store image and retrieve from stored Cache is not working - iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, caching

I'm trying to download image and store that image in cache. From next attempt, pull that image from cache if exists otherwise download that image

I've gone thru similar posts but nothing helps me to fix.

Please advice

```
    let imageCache = NSCache<NSString, UIImage>()
    func getImage(from url: URL, completion: @escaping ((UIImage?, Error?)->(Void))) {
        if let cachedImage = imageCache.object(forKey: url.absoluteString as NSString) {
            print("Image from cache")
            completion(cachedImage, nil)
        }

         NetworkOperations().downloadImage(from: url) { (data, error) in
            if let error = error {
                completion(nil, error)
            } else if let imgData = data, let image = UIImage(data: imgData) {
                self.imageCache.setObject(image, forKey: url.absoluteString as NSString)
                print("Image from cache")
                completion(image, nil)
            }

        }
    }
```

When i call this method, it always picks by downloading image. I'm struck here

Comment: Is `imageCache` being created each time?

Comment: I think so. setObject line executes everytime

Comment: I'm asking about the `let imageCache = NSCache<NSString, UIImage>()` line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a shared `cache` at the application level and add/retrieve/remove wherever you want as below,

```
class ImageCache {

    private init() {}

    static let shared = NSCache<NSString, UIImage>()
}
```

**Usage**

```
func getImage(from url: URL, completion: @escaping ((UIImage?, Error?)->(Void))) {
        if let cachedImage = ImageCache.shared.object(forKey: url.absoluteString as NSString) {
            print("Image from cache")
            completion(cachedImage, nil)
        }

         NetworkOperations().downloadImage(from: url) { (data, error) in
            if let error = error {
                completion(nil, error)
            } else if let imgData = data, let image = UIImage(data: imgData) {
                ImageCache.shared.setObject(image, forKey: url.absoluteString as NSString)
                print("Image from cache")
                completion(image, nil)
            }

        }
    }
```

I hope, this will fix the issue and it should also give you an insight of what is being wrong with your implementation. Most probably your cache has the same scope as the `object` where it is declared and used so once the `object` is `de-initialised`, the cache will also be released.

In the above implemtation, cache is declared as a `static` so that it is never `de-initialized` but you can clear the cache anytime with the following,

```
ImageCache.shared.removeAllObjects()
```

Comment: That's really helpful. I understood where it went wrong. Thanks @Kamran